# Numpy 2-D boolean mask

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I am trying to create a boolean mask for a 2-D numpy array of shape (100, 785), but I my mask comes out as (100, 1).

```
ywx = np.multiply(y_t, x_t @ w)
mask = ywx < 1
```

where mask is my (100, 1) boolean mask.
I am currently doing the following to expand it:

```
expanded_mask = np.array([np.repeat(boolean[0], 785) for boolean in mask])
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: We need more info, mostly `shape`s. Target a [mcve].

Comment: What's the shape of `ymx`?

Comment: Also why does `mask` have to be (100, 785)?  What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: `mask.repeat(785, 1)`

Comment: so `ywx` has shape (100,). For any `numpy` array of size (100, X) you can now directly apply the mask to this array without this expansion. As it stands, we have no way of knowing what you want to do and as such no way to help you.